# How to share nix store among multiple aws instances?

Tags: aws, nixos, nix

I am using nixops and want to reduce disk space consumption by sharing nix store among instances.

Possible implementation:

- share `/nix/store` store through elastic file system.
- make cron job on random machine inside network that runs `nix-collect-garbage -d`. This will remove all packages that are not linked with first machine: actually stale packages and packages of other machines inside network. To restore them first machine triggers `nixos-rebuild switch` on other machines inside network.

Can this be done better/does this make sense?

Comment: Not sure if this works for NixOS, but I once shared the nix store via NFS: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NFS#Nix_store_on_NFS You could probably put overlayfs on top of NFS to allow local modifications.

Comment: The nixos iso also shows how readonly and read-write layers can be overlayed: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/installer/cd-dvd/iso-image.nix#L315

Comment: Only having a single read-only /nix/store has it caveats as the nix store also store configuration files. Sharing the same elastic filesystem could work so, if your network storage implements posix file locking. `nix-collect-garbage` usually relies on seeing other processes using files - in a distributed settings it might delete files in use.

Comment: Mic92's link updated: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/2de1bd778ccc90cef078970106bf7fc67fb23c54/nixos/modules/installer/cd-dvd/iso-image.nix#L730